# PathNotFoundException in the groovy script SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

While executing this script in the line 2, error message is getting, instead of null response.

If there is no "success_text" in the response, it should show null value instead of error.

```
def response = context.expand( '${moneytransfer#Response}' )
def id =parse(response).read('$.success_text') 
log.info id
```

Could you please help me, is there anyway "id" value returns null, if the success_text not found

Comment: Sounds like you need an [if statement with null check](https://www.danvega.dev/blog/2013/08/20/groovys-null-safe-operator/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't share the `parse` and `read` method it's hard to know what is happening under the hood. However in groovy there is a [null-safe operator `?.`](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator), it avoids NPE returning `null` instead.

I suspect that the problem is inside your methods, however you can try with it:

```
def response = context.expand( '${moneytransfer#Response}' )
def id =parse(response)?.read('$.success_text') 
log.info id
```